# Doubts on differentiable manifolds proof: Smooth retraction of compact manifold onto its boundary

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds

This is from Guillemin and Pollack chapter 2.

Theorem: If $X$ is any compact manifold with boundary, then there exists no smooth map $g:X\to \partial X$ with $\partial g:\partial X\to \partial X$ the identity.

The proof proceeds by contradiction: Suppose such a $g$ exists and let $z\in \partial X$ be a regular value. They claim this follows by Sard's theorem, but I don't see why? Couldn't the boundary have measure zero (it could even be empty)?

My second question: They also claim that the codimension of $g^{-1}(z)$ in $X$ is equal to the codimension of $z\in \partial X$, and so is $\dim X-1$, but why is this true?

Comment: The point 1) is an application of the generalization of Sard's theorem proved page $62$ : for any smooth map $f : X \to Y$, $X$ being a manifold possibly with boundary, then almost every point is a regular value of both $f$ and $f_{|\partial X}$.

For the second point, this is also an application of the theorem abut transversality page $60$.

Comment: @N.H. thank you very much. if you would like to answer, I would be happy to accept, otherwise I would just delete this.

Comment: Sure I can make an answer. In fact I never read the book by Guillemin and Pollack but it seems to me that it's the same content as Milnor's book on differentiable topology (probably with more details).

Comment: @N.H. yes we are using them in tandem. Milnor doesn't have much exposition haha. Anyway, thank you for your answer. It was an error to skip the transversality section obviously.

Comment: Sure ! In fact, I'm glad the book you're reading is more detailed, since I was never sure to be able to fill rigorously the details... And now I see 50 pages where Milnor was writing 2 pages haha, but on the other hand it's a very pretty book !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point 1) is an application of the generalization of Sard's theorem proved page $62$ : for any smooth map $f : X \to Y$, $X$ being a manifold possibly with boundary, then almost every point is a regular value of both $f$ and $f_{|\partial X}$.

For the second point, this is also an application of the theorem concerning transversality page $60$.

Comment: There should be some condition on $Y$ there.  For example, $\dim X\geq \dim Y$ or something like that.  (I don't currently have access to the book, so I can't look it up.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito : Are you sure ? If $\dim X < \dim Y$, then the image has measure zero, so almost every point is a regular value for $f$ and $f_{| \partial X}$.

Comment: Duh!.  Objection withdawn and +1 from me.